# Peer (MultiPeer Connectivity) is connected but not stored in connectedPeers

Tags: ios, iphone, multipeer-connectivity

I have one device that is advertising itself to 2 other browsers. Once both browsers connect to the advertiser for the first time, everything works well (each peer is connected with one another).

Once browser 1 disconnects and reconnects, browser 2 no longer has browser 1 as a connected peer even though they are connected according to peer:didChangeState:. However, the advertiser successfully has 2 connected peers. Any ideas what could be wrong or how I could further debug this?

(Note: I'm using MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceBrowser and creating my own custom advertiser/browser view controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Just found a fix!

Initializing a new peerID, browser, and session (using the new peerID) before reconnecting fixed it for me.